# Adding a custom line to table of contents containing LaTeX code

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I want to add a custom line to my table of contents. This custom line consists of two elements: an abbreviation and a title. The abbreviation may consist of anything between 1 and 3 characters, but independently of its length should always take up exactly the same, predefined space, such that the titles are well aligned under each other in the table of contents.

The following minimal example almost works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Some starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\parbox{3em}{A01} Some title}

Foo

\section*{Some other starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\parbox{3em}{Z} Some other title}

Bar

\end{document}
```

As you can see below, the abbreviations appear in the table of contents with the same length and the titles are neatly aligned below each other:

[image: Minimal working example]

However, the PDF index (which can be seen in the sidepane of Acrobat Reader, for instance) generated by hyperref is messed up. The entries are:

- 3emA01 Some title
- 3emZ Some other title

For some reason the "3em" part is taken into account when generating the PDF index. This is a no-go, the PDF index should contain:

- A01 Some title
- Z Some other title

How can I achieve this? Note that I am not opposed to another solution than using a `\parbox` as above, as long as the abbreviations take up a predefined fixed space and the titles are aligned in the table of contents, while the PDF index is also properly generated.

Comment: You can't put a \parbox into bookmarks section. Using the `tocloft` package will provide a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the section number box can be changed with the `tocloft` package and `\cftsecnumwidth` length (I added `1.5em` here, change to more appropiate values at will)
The `bookmarksnumbered=true` feature will use the faked section number `A01` and `Z` in the bookmarks, wheres as `\numberline` is responsible for the toc entry

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.5em}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{A01}Some title}
\section*{Some starred section}

Foo

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{Z}Some other title}
\section*{Some other starred section}

Bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Both yours and Heiko's answers were excellent. I did not know about `\numberline`, which does exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa: All versions worked, mine is perhaps the shortest one ;-) And Heiko's answers should work of course, since he is the author of  `hyperref` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`\parbox` is not supported for bookmarks, which only consist of single lines. The following example defines the markup macro `\abbrnum`, which is redefined for the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\abbrnum}[1]{%
  \parbox{3em}{#1}%
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\abbrnum\@firstofone}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Some starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abbrnum{A01} Some title}

Foo

\section*{Some other starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abbrnum{Z} Some other title}

Bar

\end{document}
```

> [image: Bookmarks]

If numbered sections are not used, then the usual `\numberline` can be used. The space for the number can be increased either by a better class or package or by patching:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

% Patch \l@section to increase space for number from 1.5em to 3em.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}%
                   {\setlength\@tempdima{3em}}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\l@section could not be patched}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Some starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{A01}Some title}

Foo

\section*{Some other starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{Z}Some other title}

Bar

\end{document}
```

Having section numbers in the table of contents and the bookmarks, but not at the actual section location looks odd to me, therefore I would just redefine `\thesection` to show the new numbers. Then also the references work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

% Patch \l@section to increase space for number from 1.5em to 3em.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}%
                   {\setlength\@tempdima{3em}}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\l@section could not be patched}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{A01}
\section{Some starred section}

Foo

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Z}
\section{Some other starred section}

Bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right of course, my minimal example was maybe a bit contrived. Actually I'm using my own macro for starting a new section which also labels the actual section, but that would have been too involved for a minimal example. On the other hand using `\subsection` instead of `\subsection*` in the minimal example would also be weird because then a line would already be added to the table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

Here I introduce `\preplabel{}`, which places the label in a `\ttfamily` right-aligned field, so that all labels take the same width on the contents page. If left-alignment is preferred, that change is trivial... just redefine `\preplabelhelp` to the following:

```
\def\preplabelhelp#1#2#3{\ttfamily#1#2#3\ifx#3\relax~\fi\ifx#2\relax~\fi~~~\rmfamily}
```

Of course, because the PDF bookmark font is not `\ttfamily` and does not permit font changes in its midst, the spacing will not appear uniform in the bookmark itself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\preplabel[1]{\preplabelhelp#1\relax\relax}
\def\preplabelhelp#1#2#3{\ttfamily\ifx#3\relax~\fi\ifx#2\relax~\fi#1#2#3~~~\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Some starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\preplabel{A01} Some title}

Foo

\section*{Some other starred section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\preplabel{Z} Some other title}

Bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the left-aligned version:

[image]